# Как получить доступ к data text-fields в vuetifyjs?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify

Выводится много кнопок в разных компонентах со своими правилами валидации. Как получить достпу к свойству `valid` возвращаемой в `data` текстового поля (`<v-text-field>`) **vuetifyjs**?

```
<template>
  <div>
    <v-container fluid row wrap>             
      <v-layout justify-space-around>
        <v-flex xs12 sm12 md6 lg2 xl2>
           <v-text-field
             v-model="preorder.marking"
             label="Маркировка"
            >
           </v-text-field>     
        </v-flex>
      </v-layout>
    </v-container>
  </div>
</template>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Скролим вниз -->

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У `v-text-field` нет свойства `valid`. Приведите упрощенный код.

Comment: @РустамГимранов подправил

Comment: Помимо `vuetifyjs`, какие еще используются плагины? И не совсем понятно, что вы хотите от `valid`.

Comment: @РустамГимранов, много, хочу значение. Так как оно вычисляемое.

Comment: ну так через $refs доставайте... и ли может у компонента есть событие `change` - через него

Comment: Да тут не понятно: в вопросе звучит, что в поле `data`, в комментарии - оно уже вычисляемое. Вы бы уточнили какой именно плагин валидации, привели бы код `script` компонента. Пишите `this.valid` )

Comment: @РустамГимранов  и там будет `undefined`. Вы думаете я бы задал вопрос, будь всё так просто. На картинках я приложил вложенность. Так это ж  компонент `vuetify`.

Comment: @РустамГимранов я думал вас интересуют другие плагины. Для валидации не использую плагинов.

Comment: Получилось ч/з `$refs` достать `valid`?

Comment: @РустамГимранов нет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `vm.$vnode.data.model` - содержит объект с названием параметра, который записан в v-model и значение этого параметра
2. У формы взять значение валидная она или нет можно через $ref: `vm.$refs.form.value`

Где `vm` - объект Vue

Comment: В комментариях много чего напишут. Я ошибался. Посмотрев исходники библиотеки: класс `VTextField` наследуется от `VInput`, который имеет миксин `validatable` у которого есть поле [valid](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/9316760cfdc9d86296f25acd398a6874b8d28c03/packages/vuetify/src/mixins/validatable.ts#L52). Все это дело кружится вокруг [Form data validation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Form_validation). Хотя в [документации](https://vuetifyjs.com/ru/components/text-fields#api) не указан props `valid`.

Comment: Свойство `valid` для `v-text-field` доступно также ч/з `$refs`.